# Conditional probability as a function

Tags: probability, elementary-probability

**Sample space (S)** is a **set** of all possible outcomes of a random experiment.

> $S = \{x | x $is an outcome$\}$

**Event (E)** is a **subset** of sample space.

> $E \subseteq S$

**Probability** is a **function** from a set (Event) to $[0,1]$

> $p : E -> [0,1]$

My doubt is that whether conditional probability is also a form of probability, whose argument is a set? Is conditional probability a function?

If yes, what is the argument of the conditional probability function?

Comment: Is a function of a [*pair* of events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Definition).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is it true that A/B is a set?

Comment: NO; but $A$ and $B$ are sets.

Comment: Then A/B is a non-mathematical terminology? otherwise, what is $A/B$? Is it a number/ set/ .. ? Can we write A/B interms of sets A and B?

Comment: $P(A/B)$ is a *symbol*. We may write $P(A_B)$ or some other way... We define: "the *conditional probability* as the measure of the probability of an event $A$ given that (by assumption, presumption, assertion or evidence) another event $B$ has occurred." Thus, it is definied for a couple of events.

Answer (score 1):

For an event $E$ s.t. $P(E)>0$, the answer is yes. Since $P(A|E)=\frac{P(A\cap E)}{P(E)}$ , we can define a new probability measure $P_E$ s.t. $P_E(A)=P(A|E)=\frac{P(A\cap E)}{P(E)}$. All the properties of a probability measure hold for $P_E$.

In some cases it is possible to define a conditional probability measure on events $E$ s.t. $P(E)=0$, but that is more complicated.

Comment: In answer, you defined a  new probability measure, which takes input a set $A$, but for actual conditional probability function?

Comment: It takes a set $A$ but instead of giving the original probability, it gives the probability under the condition that $E$ happened.

Comment: Just for clarification, $P(A|E)$ means the probability that $A$ occurs given that $E$ occured.